# tensorflow object detection api training gives empty checkpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to train mobilenet SSD with my custom dataset using the TensorFlow object detection API and TF 2.2.0
the command I used looks like this

```sh
 
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH="./object_detection/configs/tf2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8_edit.config"
 MODEL_DIR="/media/mai/The_rest/Linux_files/work_datasets/ssd_ckpts/train2"
 NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=50
SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1


python ./object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH}  \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS}    \
    --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=${SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

The training process starts and ends without any explicit errors (tho I do know that it can't find cuDNN, I decided to train the demo on cpu for now)

Terminal output:

```
..
..
..
..
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.axis
W0817 13:33:36.500709 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.500744 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.beta
W0817 13:33:36.500780 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.500816 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.500867 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.4.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.axis
W0817 13:33:36.500936 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.500972 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501009 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501059 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501094 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.7.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.axis
W0817 13:33:36.501131 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.501166 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501202 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501238 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501274 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.2.10.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.axis
W0817 13:33:36.501310 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.501346 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501382 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501417 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501454 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.axis
W0817 13:33:36.501489 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.501526 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501561 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501596 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501632 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.4.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.axis
W0817 13:33:36.501668 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.501703 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501739 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501775 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501811 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.7.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.axis
W0817 13:33:36.501847 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.501882 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.beta
W0817 13:33:36.501918 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.501954 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.501990 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.3.10.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.axis
W0817 13:33:36.502026 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.502061 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.beta
W0817 13:33:36.502097 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.502133 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.502169 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.1.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.axis
W0817 13:33:36.502204 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.502240 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.beta
W0817 13:33:36.502275 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.502311 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.502346 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.4.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.axis
W0817 13:33:36.502382 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.502417 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.beta
W0817 13:33:36.502453 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.502489 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.502525 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.7.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.axis
W0817 13:33:36.502561 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.axis
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.gamma
W0817 13:33:36.502596 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.gamma
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.beta
W0817 13:33:36.502632 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.beta
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.moving_mean
W0817 13:33:36.502668 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.moving_mean
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.moving_variance
W0817 13:33:36.502704 140115518416704 util.py:144] Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).model._box_predictor._base_tower_layers_for_heads.box_encodings.4.10.moving_variance
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
W0817 13:33:36.502742 140115518416704 util.py:152] A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues. Use expect_partial() on the load status object, e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore(...).expect_partial(), to silence these warnings, or use assert_consumed() to make the check explicit. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint#loading_mechanics for details.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
W0817 13:33:36.508932 140115518416704 dataset_builder.py:83] num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
Killed
```

the process was killed in this run but it sometimes just ends
it outputs 3 files and one folder called train (.meta is missing)

```
ls 
checkpoint  ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001  ckpt-1.index  train
```

and when I try to run tensor board it is mostly empty till the crash, and when it crashes it shows that it did 2 steps and all values are never changed
even tho the number of steps is set to 50 for this demo in the config file
[image: tensorboard output]

I did find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609378/tensorflow-object-detection-api-training-fails-silently) but with no answers

Comment: Same error for me. I know it's been a long time but did you manage to find an answer to that specific question?

Comment: I don't remember which ended this specific problem,but of the things I changed I remember changing the model itself and its config file to another version of the mobilenet ssd v2